# How to use DiagnosticableTreeMixin with lists?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am using Flutter Provider with a DiagnosticableTreeMixin in order to keep track of my state in the debugger.

However i need to set up the DiagnosticableTreeMixin to work with a List.

For Example

1) Model Setup

```
class MyClass with DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  MyClass({this.value1, this.value2});

  final String value1;
  final String value2;


  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(StringProperty('value1', value1));
    properties.add(StringProperty('value2', value2));
  }
}
```

2) Provider Setup

```
class MyClassProvider with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  List<MyClass> _listOfMyClass = [];
  List<MyClass> get listOfClass => _listOfMyClass;

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);

    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty<List<MyClass>>(
        'ListOfMyClass', _listOfMyClass));
  }
}
```

In the debugger, when i open the MyClassProvider and look into the value i would see something like:

```
ListOfMyClass:[MyClass#0bb46(value1:"123",value2:"345),MyClass#0b546(value1:"123",value2:"456"),MyClass#01b46(value1:"1
```

This is an example with 3 instances, it is always cut into one line. This is problematic when trying to track multiple values since they will be not shown at all, and it is not expandable structure so it is messy to track anything this way.

How is it possible to turn them into readable values in the debugger?

Something Like

```
ListOfMyClass:
[
 MyClass#0bb46(value1:"123",value2:"345),
 MyClass#0bb46(value1:"123",value2:"345),
 MyClass#0bb46(value1:"123",value2:"345),
 MyClass#0bb46(value1:"123",value2:"345),
 MyClass#0bb46(value1:"123",value2:"345),
 MyClass#0bb46(value1:"123",value2:"345)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple

***IterableProperty***

Or create class by yourself
(more information in flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart : 2577)

some example

```
class _SendPostPageState extends State<SendPostPage>
    with DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  bool isLoadig = true;

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    // properties.add(isLoadig);
    properties.add(IterableProperty('Array', [isLoadig]));
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff262626),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(32),
        ),
      ),
      child: ListView(
        controller: widget.scrollController,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 10,
              width: 10,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```